# Adding/updating a value in python list

Tags: python, list, coordinates

Say I have a list with coordinates in and I want to manipulate my z coordinate by 10:

```
coords = [0, 1.2, 0] # x y z
```

I have been doing the follow:

```
coords = coords[coords[0], 0, coords[2] + 10]
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong? I'm new to python and could use some help! Thank you!

Comment: This would just be `coords[2] += 10`.  Add 10 to the value two positions from the start of the list `coords`

Comment: Remove `coords` before `[coords[0], ...]`.

Comment: `coords = [coords[0], 0, coords[2] + 10]`

Comment: @codegoblin1996 did the answers solve your question? if so, consider closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to update the entire array/list, you can just access the index you require updating

```
 coords[2] = coords[2] + 10
```

coords now = `[0, 1.2, 10]`

Answer (score 0):

In order to add 10 to `coords[2]` you can just write:

```
coords[2] += 10
```